# Compare run date to current date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help figuring out how to compare the last run date to the current date and then calculate how many days between the two. I only need to compare the first row against the current date because I am sorting in descending order so that should be the last run date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    cast(getdate() AS Date) AS Today, Run_Date, COUNT(Run_Date) AS Daily_Count,
    Days_Since_Last_Run_Date = 
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Run_Date) > 1 AND LAG(Run_Date,0) OVER (ORDER BY Run_Date) <> DATEADD(DAY,+1,Run_Date)
    THEN + CAST((DATEDIFF(DAY,LAG(Run_Date,0) OVER (ORDER BY Run_Date),Run_Date)+1) AS NVARCHAR)
    ELSE ''
    END
FROM tblUnitsOfWork
WHERE Run_Date >= '2023-07-10'
GROUP BY Run_Date
ORDER BY Run_Date DESC;
```

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: This question really needs "sample data" and "expected result" (derived purely from that sample)

Comment: `case when run_date = max(run_date) over () then datediff(day, run_date, getdate()) end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simpler to use a "nested" subquery (also called "derived table") to supply the row numbers, then in the outer query use a case expression. e.g:

```
SELECT
    *
    , case when rn = 1 then datediff(day,run_date,getdate()) end as days_diff
FROM (
    SELECT
          cast(getdate() AS DATE) AS Today
        , Run_Date
        , COUNT(Run_Date) AS Daily_Count
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY Run_Date DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM tblUnitsOfWork
    WHERE Run_Date >= '2023-07-10'
    GROUP BY Run_Date
    ) AS d
ORDER BY Run_Date DESC
```

| Today | Run_Date | Daily_Count | rn | days_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-07-19 | 2023-07-15 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2023-07-19 | 2023-07-14 | 1 | 2 | *null* |
| 2023-07-19 | 2023-07-13 | 1 | 3 | *null* |
| 2023-07-19 | 2023-07-12 | 1 | 4 | *null* |
| 2023-07-19 | 2023-07-11 | 1 | 5 | *null* |
| 2023-07-19 | 2023-07-10 | 1 | 6 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fe4rGs4e)

note: You do NOT need "select distinct" if you are using `GROUP BY` - grouping automatically includes making rows "distinct"

To output empty strings in the different column convert that column to a string:

```
, case when rn = 1 then cast(datediff(day,run_date,getdate()) as varchar(6)) else '' end as
```

Comment: Paul, this works great!  I am trying to tweak the case statement so any row after row 1 is blank.  I have added an Else '' but it shows a zero.  This is in SSMS.  Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The column is establish as integer so you can't output an empty **string** UNLESS you cast/convert the value from datediff into a string. See amended answer.

Comment: btw: **case ... end** is an `expression` (not a statement) as each `case expression` evaluates to a single value (per row). Statements are much larger constructs e.g. `select statement` `update statement` etc.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it makes perfect sense.  I was too far down in the weeds on this one.